# Grep for string if contained in several consecutive lines

Tags: grep

I have a logfile in which I want to find lines that contain a specific string, if it's at least five consecutive lines that contain it.

E.g. my logfile looks like this:

```
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 030081, ts 2726949472, len 000160)
Got  RTP packet from    10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 052435, ts 174852800, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 030082, ts 2726949632, len 000160)
Got  RTP packet from    10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 052436, ts 174852960, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 030083, ts 2726949792, len 000160)
Got  RTP packet from    10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 052437, ts 174853120, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 030084, ts 2726949952, len 000160)
Got  RTP packet from    10.124.193.26:12486 (type 09, seq 052438, ts 174853280, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055416, ts 87947536, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055417, ts 87947696, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055418, ts 87947856, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055419, ts 87948016, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055420, ts 87948176, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055421, ts 87948336, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055422, ts 87948496, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055423, ts 87948656, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055424, ts 87948816, len 000160)
Sent RTP packet to      10.124.193.90:11836 (type 09, seq 055425, ts 87948976, len 000160)
```

The first lines begin with either "Sent" or "Got" alternating.
Those are fine and I am not interested in them.
Then it's consecutive lines starting with "Sent" only.
Those I want to find.
How can I use grep or another command to find them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command :

```
$ cat <filename> | awk '{ if( pre == "Sent" && $1 == "Sent" ) {print $0} ; {pre=$1} }'
```

Explanation :

Remember the first word of the last line. If it was "Sent", and if the first word of the current line is also "Sent", print current line.

Comment: Thank you. That prints when two consecutive lines start with "Sent". I would need to print only when 5 consecutive lines start with "Sent". Possible?